# SAS macro to print out change of baseline scores

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I'm looking for a way to print out change of tests scores for each subject with a SAS macro. Here is a sample of the data:

```
Subject    Visit       Date       Test       Score
001        Baseline    01/01/99   Jump       5
001        Baseline    01/01/99   Reach      3
001        Week 6      02/12/99   Jump       7
001        Week 6      02/12/99   Reach      6
002        Baseline    03/01/99   Jump       2
002        Baseline    03/01/99   Reach      4
002        Week 6      04/12/99   Jump       5
002        Week 6      04/12/99   Reach      9
```

I would like to create a macro that generates the following for each subject:

```
Subject    Visit       Date (Days from Baseline)       Test       Score    Change from Baseline Score
001        Baseline    01/01/99                        Jump       5         
                       01/01/99                        Reach      3         
001        Week 6      02/12/99    (42)                Jump       7        +2
                       02/12/99    (42)                Reach      6        +3
002        Baseline    03/01/99                        Jump       2
                       03/01/99                        Reach      4
002        Week 6      04/12/99    (42)                Jump       5        +3
                       04/12/99    (42)                Reach      9        +5
```

I believe I can just use the INTCK function for the Days from Baseline, but I'm not sure how to print out each test without retaining the 'Subject' and 'Visit' values in each row. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by test and process using a retain for date and score for computing deltas.  The print out can be done with `Proc REPORT`, formatting delta values appropriately.

Example:

```
data have; input 
Subject    Visit& $8.  Date& mmddyy8. Test $ Score; format date mmddyy8.; datalines;
001        Baseline    01/01/99   Jump       5
001        Baseline    01/01/99   Reach      3
001        Week 6      02/12/99   Jump       7
001        Week 6      02/12/99   Reach      6
002        Baseline    03/01/99   Jump       2
002        Baseline    03/01/99   Reach      4
002        Week 6      04/12/99   Jump       5
002        Week 6      04/12/99   Reach      9
run;

proc sort data=have;
  by subject test date;
run;

data for_report;

  set have;
  by subject test;

  retain base_date base_score;

  if first.subject then do;
    base_date = .;
    base_score = .;
  end;

  if first.test and visit='Baseline' then do;
    base_date = date;
    base_score = score;
  end;

  if not first.test then do;
    delta_days = intck('days', date, base_date);
    delta_score = score - base_score;
  end;

run;


proc format;
  picture plus low-0 = [best12.] other = '000000009' (prefix='+');

options missing=' ';
proc report data=for_report;
  columns subject visit date delta_days test score delta_score;
  define subject / order;
  define visit / order order=data;
  format delta_days negparen.; 
  format delta_score plus.;
run;
options missing='.';
```

[image]

An alternate report can be more subject-centric:

```
proc report data=for_report
  style(lines) = [just=left fontweight=bold]
;
  columns subject visit date delta_days test score delta_score;
  define subject / order noprint;
  define visit / order order=data;
  format delta_days negparen.; 
  format delta_score plus.;
  compute before subject;
    subj = catx(' ', "Subject:", subject);
    line subj $200.;
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. The SQL-step calculates changes from baseline. The case-when-construct is only there to suppress zeroes in the output.

Printing using group-variables in proc report means Subject- and Visit-values are not retained on every line (but note that subject is not repeated each week).

I put the code in a macro, as that was the question. It doesn't really do much, however.

```
/*  Creating test data*/
data testdata;
    input Subject $3.  @5 Visit $8.  @17 Date mmddyy10. @28 Test $5. Score;
    format date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
001 Baseline    01/01/99   Jump       5
001 Baseline    01/01/99   Reach      3
001 Week 6      02/12/99   Jump       7
001 Week 6      02/12/99   Reach      6
002 Baseline    03/01/99   Jump       2
002 Baseline    03/01/99   Reach      4
002 Week 6      04/12/99   Jump       5
002 Week 6      04/12/99   Reach      9
;

%macro baselines(dataset=);
    /*  Adding days from baseline and change from baseline. Please note that the first visit 
    must denoted as exactly "Baseline"*/
    proc sql;
        create table changes as 
        select t1.*, case when t1.date-t2.date>0 then t1.date-t2.date else . end  as days 
            "Days from baseline", case when t1.score-t2.score>0 then t1.score-t2.score else . 
            end as score_change "Change from Baseline"
        from &dataset as t1 left join (select * from &dataset where visit="Baseline") as t2
            on t1.subject=t2.subject and t1.test=t2.test
        order by subject, visit, test;

    /*  Printing the dataset. The use of subject and visit as group variables keeps SAS from repeating the values*/
    title "Changes based on the dataset &dataset";
    proc report data=changes;
        column subject visit days test score score_change;
        define subject / group;
        define visit / group;
    run;
%mend;
%baselines(dataset=testdata)
```